# How to add a generic property of Class<T> inside of an existing Class<T>

Tags: c#, generics

Not really sure how to explain it in a one-liner but here's my situation.

I have an abstract base class called "Deal" which has a property in it which is of a class "Inventory"

Now a deal can be either Cash, Finance, Lease, Wholesale or Rent-To-Own which is why it's of type Deal. It's also abstract as each of the deal types have some properties that don't apply to other but they all have a set of shared so the various deal types (i.e. - Finance, Lease, etc.) inherit from the base class Deal and have their own added methods and properties.

The same is true with another abstract class of "Inventory". Inventory can be things like car, truck, boat, RV, etc.) so therefore I have a class of Inventory.

Here's the issue:

A deal must contain a unit in inventory. For example, you finance a car or you lease an RV then you have a Deal with an inventory property of type Inventory or whatever the case may be.

When I create the Deal class and I add a property to it like SoldUnit as type Inventory, the T is inherited from the Deal class. How can I create a generic property of type Inventory inside of the Deal class?

Deal won't really work because of the number of possibilities, so how could I make a generic "SoldUnit" property which references an Inventory class inside of the Deal class? And while maintaining strict typing? I know I could make a property called SoldUnit with a type of object or dynamic, but is there a better way?

Thanks!

EDIT:

Sorry, here is an excerpt of the code: It doesn't work because type T is already a DealType, but it's the two properties [ `ret.Vehicle = new Car();` and `ret.SoldUnit = new Car();` ] that I'm trying to populate with a specific inventory type (car, truck, rv, boat, etc.) in the Get() method. The specific inventory type is determined by a flag in the database field.

Thanks again!

```
public abstract class Deal<T>
{
    public string Uid { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    public DealTypes DealType { get; set; } = DealTypes.Finance;

    public Buyer Customer { get; set; }
    public Inventory<T> Vehicle { get; set; }
    public Location Location { get; set; }
    public Inventory<T> SoldUnit { get; set; }

    public abstract T Add(string id);
    public abstract T Update(string id);
    public abstract T Get(string id);
}

public abstract class Inventory<T>
{
    public string Uid { get; internal set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    public Location Location { get; set; }
    public string StockNumber { get; set; } = "";
}

public class Cash : Deal<Cash>
{
    public decimal TradeAllowance { get; set; }
    public decimal TradePayoff { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalDown { get; set; }
    public decimal DueOnDelivery { get; set; }

    public override Cash Get(string id)
    {
        var ret = new Cash();
        ret.Customer = new Buyer();
        ret.Vehicle = new Car();
        ret.Location = new Location();
        ret.SoldUnit = new Car();
   }
}

public class Car : Inventory<Car>
{
    public decimal GrossWeight { get; set; }
    public decimal NetWeight { get; set; }
    public string Branded { get; set; } = "";
    public string FuelType { get; set; } = "";
    public string Trim { get; set; } = "";
    public string Body { get; set; } = "";
    public int Cylinders { get; set; }
    public decimal EngineSize { get; set; }
    public string TransmissionType { get; set; } = "";
    public string Suspension { get; set; } = "";
    public string InteriorColor { get; set; } = "";

    public bool OdometerExceedsLimit { get; set; }
    public bool OdometerTrueMileageUnknown { get; set; }
    public bool OdometerFiveDigit { get; set; }


    public string TitleNumber { get; set; } = "";
    public DateTime? TitleDate { get; set; }
    public string TitleState { get; set; } = "";
    public DateTime? TitleDue { get; set; }
    public DateTime? TitleReceived { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Some code, even if it doesn't compile, would really help illustrate your issue.

Comment: It looks like you could declare the abstract class Deal as `Deal<T>` and pass that `T` to `Inventory<T>` , or a `Deal<TDeal, TInventory>` with an `Inventory<TInventory>` property I guess. But it's really unclear to me what you're trying to do.

Comment: Are you just asking how to have multiple type arguments on your class?

Comment: It sounds like you may want non-generic base classes for everything, and use references to that: If non generic `DealBase` is a base class of `Deal<T>`, then a `DealBase` reference can refer to any `Deal<T>`. If you have cases where you'll want to use the same name for a non-generic property of type `object`, and a generic property of type `T`, you could look at having generic specialized classes explicitly implement a non-generic interface.

Comment: I can't really make the class     Deal<TDeal, TInventory> because then I would have to make a class for every possible combination which would be too redundant since so many of them would have the exact same code.

Comment: Is there not really a way to make the Deal<T> class have a property like: `public Inventory<AnyVehicleType> Vehicle { get; set; }`? (AnyVehicleType is just pseudo-code). Is object or dynamic typing the only way?

Answer (score 0):

I've simplified your code down somewhat to the necessary elements to make this work, but you do need to have your base classes defined like `Deal<D, I> where D : Deal<D, I> where I : Inventory<D, I>` & `Inventory<D, I> where D : Deal<D, I> where I : Inventory<D, I>` respectively.

Your code would then look like this:

```
public abstract class Deal<D, I> where D : Deal<D, I> where I : Inventory<D, I>
{
    public I Vehicle { get; set; }

    public abstract D Get(string id);
}

public abstract class Inventory<D, I> where D : Deal<D, I> where I : Inventory<D, I>
{ }

public class Cash : Deal<Cash, Car>
{
    public override Cash Get(string id)
    {
        return new Cash() { Vehicle = new Car() };
    }
}

public class Car : Inventory<Cash, Car>
{ }
```

This is what you need to do to have a strongly-typed `Vehicle` property and `Get` (etc) method.

Comment: Thanks. So by doing that, I would need a separate class for each possible combination? i.e - 

`public class Cash : Deal<Cash, Car>`

`public class Cash : Deal<Cash, Truck>`

`public class Cash : Deal<Cash, RV>`

`public class Cash : Deal<Cash, Boat>`

...

`public class Car : Inventory<Cash, Car>`

`public class Car : Inventory<Finance, Car>`

`public class Car : Inventory<Lease, Car>`

`public class Car : Inventory<Wholesale, Car>`

...

etc..